# A way to drag a chart smoothly in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

How I can drag a chart smoothly?
The chart is construct from two charts that candlestick and line chart.
The line chart is corresponding to candle chart, The line indicates low value of each candle.
these charts are overlap on a graph area.

This graph is able to drag horizontally, but it is very choppy.

About 750 candles does exists in my chart.

Drag become smoothly when the line chart is disabled, so seems like it caused by line chart.

I suppose to this graph taking time to redraw all of path commands in line.
But I dont know what make it choppy actually.

How I can fix it?

```js
margin = {top: 0, bottom: 20, left: 40, right: 20}


const f = async () => {
    let num
    let res = await fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/KiYugadgeter/f2f861798257118cb420c9cdb1f830f6/raw/b2c4217e569b3b2064f88bb7ac2f8a1e328ff516/data2.csv")
    let d = await res.text()
    let min_value = 999999999
    let max_value = 0
    data = parsed_data = d3.csvParse(d, (dt) => {
        const j = dt.date.split("-").map((i)  => {
            return parseInt(i)
        })
        const date = new Date(...j)
        high_value = parseFloat(dt.high)
        low_value = parseFloat(dt.low)
        open_value = parseFloat(dt.open)
        close_value = parseFloat(dt.close)
        if (low_value < min_value) {
            min_value = low_value
        }
        if (high_value > max_value) {
            max_value = high_value
        }
        return {
            open: open_value,
            close: close_value,
            high: high_value,
            low: low_value,
            date: date
        }
    })
    return {data: data, min: min_value, max: max_value}

}
f().then((d) => {
    let num = 0
    let recently_date = d.data[d.data.length-1].date
    let minvalue = 99999999999
    let maxvalue = 0
    recently_date.setMinutes(recently_date.getMinutes() - (recently_date.getMinutes() % 30))
    recently_date.setSeconds(0)
    recently_date.setMilliseconds(0)
    const limit_date = (recently_date - (60 * 90 * 1000))
    const data = d.data.filter((d) => {
        num++
        if (d.low < minvalue) {
            minvalue = d.low
        }
        if (d.high > maxvalue) {
            maxvalue = d.high
        }
        return true
    })
    const svg = d3.select("svg")
    const xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain(
        [
            limit_date,
            recently_date
        ]
    ).nice().range([margin.left, 600-margin.left-margin.right])
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([(maxvalue - (maxvalue%1000) + 1000), (minvalue - (minvalue%1000) - 1000)]).range([0, 410-margin.top-margin.bottom])
    //console.log(recently_date, limit_date)
    const canvas = svg.append("g").attr("width", 600).attr("height", 410)
    const xaxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks().tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M"))
    //console.log(canvas.attr("width"))
    //console.log(svg.node().width.baseVal.value-300)
    const clip = svg.append("clipPath").attr("id", "clip").append("rect").attr("width", 600-margin.left-margin.right).attr("height", 410-margin.bottom-margin.top).attr("x", margin.left).attr("y", 0)
    const g = canvas // Data group
        .append("g")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "square")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .join("g")
        .classed("ticks", true)
        /*.attr("transform", (d) => {
            return `translate(${xScale(d.date)},0)`
            }
        )*/
    g.append("line")
        .attr("y1", (d) => yScale(d.high))
        .attr("y2", (d) => yScale(d.low))
        .attr("x1", (d) => xScale(d.date))
        .attr("x2", (d) => xScale(d.date))
        .attr("stroke-width", 0.6)
        .classed("line_high_low", true)

    g.append("line")
        .attr("y1", (d) => yScale(d.open))
        .attr("y2", (d) => yScale(d.close))
        .attr("x1", (d) => xScale(d.date))
        .attr("x2", (d) => xScale(d.date))
        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
        .attr("stroke", (d) => d.open > d.close ? d3.schemeSet1[0]
            : d.close > d.open ? d3.schemeSet1[2] : d3.schemeSet1[8]
        )
        .classed("line_open_close", true)
    
    const linefunc = (xScale, yScale) => {
        return d3.line()
        .x((d) => {
            if (isNaN(d.date)) {
                return 0
            }
            let retval = xScale(d.date)
            return retval
        })
        .y((d) => {
            if (isNaN(d.low)) {
                return 0
            }
            let retval = yScale(d.low)
            return retval
        })
    }

        g.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "#00ff00")
            .attr("d", linefunc(xScale, yScale))

    const group_x = canvas
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + String(410-margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")") // X axis
        .call(xaxis).style("font-size", "5")
    const yaxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
    const group_y = canvas
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + String(margin.left) + ",0)") // Y axis
        .call(yaxis)
        .style("font-size", "5")
   


zoom_func = d3.zoom().on("zoom", (e) => {
    let newX = e.transform.rescaleX(xScale)
    let newscale = xaxis.scale(newX)
    group_x.call(newscale)
    //g.selectAll(".ticks").data(data).join(".ticks line").attr("x1", (d) => {
    g.selectAll("line").join("line").attr("x1", (d) => {
        return newX(d.date)
    }).attr("x2", (d) => {return newX(d.date)})
    g.selectAll("path").attr("transform", `translate(${e.transform.x} 0)`)
    //.attr("transform", (d) => `translate({$newX(d.date)}, 0)`) this is not use
})
    svg.call(zoom_func)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 600 410">
        </svg>

     <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet of fiddle?

Comment: So sorry that I using different version of d3.js (latest on fiddle is 5.x, I using 6.x)
So it may does not work correctly on fiddle.

Comment: You can add a link to D3 V6 (click on 'Resources' in the sidebar of JSFiddle)

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky thanks!!
Working code has uploaded as a fiddle

Comment: Seems to be you re-render all your bars on each zoom/pan event. What you should do is to use enter/exit pattern of D3 and filter out the items outside visible range before rendering

Comment: How I can filtering elements in invisible area then stop drawing these element?